# How to have Jackson use a method to serialize a class to JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, customization

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Test t;

    public MyClass() {
        t = new Test(50);
    }
}

public class Test {
    private int test;

    public Test(int test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public String toCustomString() {
        return test + "." + test;
    }
}
```

When Jackson serializes an instance of `MyClass`, it will look like the following:

`{"t":{"test":50}}`

Is there any annotation I can put in the `Test` class to force Jackson to invoke the `toCustomString()` method whenever serializing a `Test` object?

I'd like to see one of the following outputs when Jackson serializes an instance of `MyClass`:

`{"t":"50.50"}`

`{"t":{"test":"50.50"}}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to produce

```
{"t":"50.50"}
```

you can use [`@JsonValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) which indicates

> that results of the annotated "getter" method (which means signature
>   must be that of getters; non-void return type, no args) is to be used
>   as the single value to serialize for the instance.

```
@JsonValue
public String toCustomString() {
    return test + "." + test;
}
```

If you want to produce

```
{"t":{"test":"50.50"}}
```

you can use a custom [`JsonSerializer`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html).

```
class TestSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Integer value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(value + "." + value);
    }
}
...
@JsonSerialize(using = TestSerializer.class)
private int test;
```

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for `@JsonProperty` annotation. Just put it to your method:

```
@JsonProperty("test")
public String toCustomString() {
    return test + "." + test;
}
```

Also, Jackson consistently denied to serialize `MyClass`, so to avoid problems you can add a simple getter to `t` property.

Comment: Jackson looks for getters and @JsonProperty annotated methods while serializing. The output would be `{"t":"50.50"}` in your case.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the point. To produce your output, property value should be `test`, I'm editing now.

Comment: I like your answer as an easier alternative to producing `{"t":{"test":"50.50"}}` instead of using a custom serializer.  Thanks.